# Parallelization of a simple iteration function in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to use parallelization using mutiprocessing to achieve good execution time in an iteration function but I was unable to do that.

My function is this

```
    for i in range(len(self.set)):
        degree = self.__degree__(self.set[i])
        self.subsets.append(degree)
```

I call it using

```
self.__build__()
```

--

I tried to make a parallel version like that:

```
    def __buildParallel__(self, i):
        degree = self.__degree__(self.set[i])
        self.subsets[i].append(degree)
```

I call the parallel version using

```
    import multiprocessing as mp
    pool = mp.Pool()  
    pool.map(self.__buildParallel__, self.set)
```

Example:

I want to parallelize the **build** function

```
import math
class Testing(object):
    def __init__(self, inputSet):
        self.set = inputSet
        self.subsets = []
        self.__build__()

    def __build__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.set)):
            degree = self.__degree__(self.set[i])
            self.subsets.append(degree)
                               
    def __degree__(self, element):
        return element[0] * 0.01

anObject = Testing([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
```

--

Attempted parallel version

```
import math
import multiprocessing as mp

class Testing(object):
    def __init__(self, inputSet):
        self.set = inputSet
        self.subsets = []
        pool = mp.Pool()  
        pool.map(self.__buildParallel__, self.set)

    def __buildParallel__(self, i):
        degree = self.__degree__(self.set[i])
        self.subsets[i].append(degree)
                               
    def __degree__(self, element):
        return element[0] * 0.01

anObject = Testing([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
```

What happens is that the program simply does not run and all processors reach 100% usage.
What could be happening?

thanks

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't post it as an answer. (Unless you actually want to *answer* the question.)

Comment: The example doesn't use `multiprocessing`. The example should demonstrate the problem you observe.

Comment: ok. I posted two versions.

Comment: The multiprocessing example raises `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`, it does not "not run and all processors reach 100% usage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any modifications made to a class in a process do so in the context of that process and won't change the original class.  With `pool.map`, the return values of the mapped function will be collected and returned.

Note that there is overhead in creating the pool processes so this trivial example would normally run slower in parallel, but I've added a sleep to appear that the parallel work takes some time.

```py
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Testing(object):
    def __init__(self, inputSet):
        self.set = inputSet
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            self.subsets = pool.map(self.__buildParallel__,self.set)

    def __buildParallel__(self, i): # i is just one element, not whole set
        time.sleep(5)  # build time would be 25+ seconds if not parallel
        return self.__degree__(i)
                               
    def __degree__(self, element):
        return element[0] * 0.01

if __name__ == '__main__':
    anObject = Testing([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
    print(anObject.set)
    print(anObject.subsets)
```

Result (after 5 seconds):

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
```

Comment: Mark, can you help me on a new question? thanks so much!!